# VLOOKUP if there is more than one value associated to a name

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following situation:

```
Adam    White
Adam    Black
Adam    Black
Ben     White
Ben     White
Clark   Black
Clark   Black
```

And I would like to get the following answer from excel:

```
Adam    Both
Ben     White
Clark   Black
```

In conclusion I have more different names in the left column and two values in the right one. I want to know for each name which appears in the left column if it has only White, only Black ore both colors associated in the right column.

Comment: What do you mean by "situation"? Are those two columns? Please edit/specify your question.

Comment: Sorry, it is the first time, that i am posting. Yes, I meant I have two columns.

Comment: No problem. You should also edit you're question though, don't just add this info in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first check if both are present with COUNTIFS.  If so, then return `Both` Else use VLOOKUP to return the one:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,D1,B:B,"Black"),COUNTIFS(A:A,D1,B:B,"White")),"Both",VLOOKUP(D1,A:B,2,FALSE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest another approach that seems a better fit than using VLOOKUP.

[image]

The formula in E1, copied down for the list of names:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A:A=D1)*(B:B="White")),IF(SUMPRODUCT((A:A=D1)*(B:B="Black")),"Both","White"),"Black")
```

SUMPRODUCT lets you handle the multiple columns similar to an array formula, looking for combinations of conditions.  A zero result is treated as `False` by the IF test; any positive number is treated as `True`.

Note that this is very simplified logic that doesn't test for error conditions, it relies on the data complying with the rules; the nested IF logic assumes that every column B entry must be either `Black` or `White`, and that every column D lookup entry is a name that is contained in column A.

Comment: Of course you could use your `=CHOOSE((Black)+(White*2), …)` trick here, too.   It would make it a lot easier to expand to three or maybe four colors (but beyond that lies a rabbit hole of madness).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overcomplicated formulas, I would recommend to go for a pivot table, which will give you name in row, colour in column and count of colour in the values. Then you can make a simple formula to establish if a particular combination exists or not.

The benefits are:

- it is much easier & intuitive to make & maintain then nested IFs with SUMPRODUCTs or even array formulas,
- it is easier to expand on in case you have multiple possible values.

Comment: This idea has potential but it leaves a lot to the imagination as far as getting to the actual desired result.  Consider expanding it with an actual example to illustrate how to accomplish it and what the result would look like (many Excel users have never used pivot tables).

Answer (score 0):

@Eleshar's answer suggests using a pivot table.  If you're starting from scratch, that's not a bad way to do the heavy lifting of extracting a unique list of names and summarizing the data (and a pivot table makes that part easy).  However, that still leaves translating the pivot table results into the desired form.  I'll build on that suggestion and show another approach to get the final result that hasn't been presented yet.

[image]

**Pivot Table**

The data is in columns A and B.  The Pivot table result is in D1:F5.  If you've never used a pivot table, select the data range and Insert Pivot Table from the menu.  I'm using LO Calc, so the user interface looks a little different, but you get a wizard that looks similar to this:

[image]

From the Available Fields, drag `Name` to the Rows box, `Color` to the Columns box, and `Color`, again, to the Data Fields (in Excel, that box is labeled `Values`).  In Excel, the aggregation already defaults to Count.  Calc has an option to deselect row and column totals.  My old Excel automatically produces those totals; you can right-click on their labels and you get a menu that includes removing them.  Specify a destination for the pivot table that doesn't overwrite the data (I picked D1).

So with a few clicks and selections, you will end up with a table like what is shown on the previous image in D:F.

**Translation to result**

The pivot table provides the basis for the results shown in column G, which is what I'll focus on here.  The formula in G3:

```
=CHOOSE((E3>0)+(F3>0)*2,"Black","White","Both")
```

CHOOSE uses a value as an index to select from a list; an index value of `1` selects the first value, `2` the second, etc.  In this formula, if the count in the Black column is greater than zero, the formula produces a `1` (Boolean value for a True result).  If the count in the White column is greater than zero, it produces a `2`.  So if there is only Black, the index is `1`; only White, the index is `2`; and both, the index is `3`.

Answer (score -1):

**I've used little different approach to solve the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

1. To make the Formula Dynamic write both the criteria, **White** in Cell `H48` and **Black** in `I48`.
2. In Cell `H50` write this Array Formula to generate list of Unique Names.

   ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($E$50:$E$56, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($H$49:H49, $E$50:$E$56), 0)),"")}
   ```

**Note,** *finish this Formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill it down.*

3. Write this Formula in Cell `I50` & fill down.

`=IFERROR(IF(AND($E$50:$E$56=H50,SUMPRODUCT(($F$50:$F$56=$H$48)+($F$50:$F$56=$I$48))>1),"Both",INDEX(F50:F56,MATCH(H50,E50:E56,0))),"")`

**N.B.** *Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Just write your concern to down vote it !!